# Venn Diagram how to spread circles and show labels names

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am struggling with [VennDiagram](https://cran.r-project.org/package=VennDiagram) to show my data. I am trying to plot 3 circles and show the labels but always I get the circles very overlapped makes it difficult to be understood. and when I tried to show the labels it shows only for some and they're out of their actual place.
below is my code and output:

```
library(VennDiagram)

data_venn22 <- read.csv('https://srv-file8.gofile.io/download/tRddKd/data_venn.csv',
                        sep=";",header = TRUE)

AA <- as.character(data_venn22$C1[!is.na(data_venn22$C1)])
BB <- as.character(data_venn22$C2[!is.na(data_venn22$C2)])
CC <- as.character(data_venn22$C3[!is.na(data_venn22$C3)])
DD <- as.character(data_venn22$C4[!is.na(data_venn22$C4)])
EE <- as.character(data_venn22$C5[!is.na(data_venn22$C5)])

GR1  <- c(AA,BB)
GR2 <- c(EE,DD)
GR3 <- c(CC)

x <- list(GR1=GR1 , GR2=GR2 , GR3=GR3 )

ven_p <- venn.diagram( x, filename=NULL, 
                    fill = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                    alpha = 0.50,
                    col = "transparent")

#### Calculate overlap
overlaps <- calculate.overlap(x)

## label names
ven_p[[7]]$label <- paste(overlaps[[2]], collapse = "\n") 

ven_p[[9]]$label <- paste(overlaps[[1]], collapse = "\n") 

ven_p[[10]]$label <- paste(overlaps[[6]], collapse = "\n") 

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(ven_p)
```

output:

[image]

is it possible to have an output like this below? in which one could write the labels in boxes beside the plot or anywhere like table:

[image]

EDIT:

alternatively; is it possible to print the results as `dataframe` , I mean the items that are both common and uncommon between circles ? in my code I was able, manually, to determine some of the labels but not all. for example I didn't identify number 10.

Comment: What package are you using? Although this could be a great feature, doubt it is implemented.

Comment: @zx8754 I use `VennDiagram` package, I don't know why the circles are overlapped like that, is it just because the package analyze the data this way or something can be modified externally